# UITableView Selection & Deselection

Tags: iphone

I am having two tableviews if the 1st table row gets selected then automatically deselect the row in 2nd table if it is previously selected. Kindly anyone help me in this. Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you select a row in your second table you have to store the selected index in a variable of your view controller. Within

```
didSelectRowAtIndexPath
```

of your first table you send

```
deselectRowAtIndexPath
```

message to your second table. Storing the selected item in a variable may be unnecessary if you manage to receive the selected index in your second table otherwise